# rails 3, ruby, jquery token input and koala

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, koala

I need some help in figuring out a module that i'm working on. As mentioned i'm using rails 3, jquery token.input and koala for facebook integration. 
What i'm trying to accomplish is to get hold of all the friends of a user from facebook and use jquery tokeninput to select certain friends. After the user clicks on submit the ids of the friends are saved in the database. What ryan showed us in his wonderful screen cast is how to search the database but the situation that i'm encountering is search through an array(two dimensional) and update in the user interface.

Controller Code:

```
def index 
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(access_token)
  @friends = @graph.get_connections("me","friends")
  # now the @friends contains all the friends of the user, how do i get something
  # like to work Friends.where("%params[:q]%") on @friends

  respond_to do |format| 
    format.html
    format.json {:render :json => @friends} 
  end 
end
```

how to i search through an array now there is something i can do like

```
@friends.include?('%params[:q]%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-select) to return only the friends you need

```
pry(main)> @friends
=> [{"name"=>"Foo bar", "id"=>"1"},
 {"name"=>"Bar Foo", "id"=>"2"},
 {"name"=>"Mark Zuckerberg", "id"=>"4"}]
pry(main)> params[:q]
=> ["1", "2"]
pry(main)> @friends.select{|friend| params[:q].include? friend['id']}                                                                                                              
=> [{"name"=>"Foo bar", "id"=>"1"}, {"name"=>"Bar Foo", "id"=>"2"}]
```

However I would suggest to avoid fetching all the friends if you want only some of them. You can do an fql query with a condition:

```
pry(main)> graph.fql_multiquery(query1: "select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() and uid2 IN (#{params[:q].join(',')})", query2: 'select uid , name from user where uid in (select uid2 from #query1)')
=> {"query1"=>[{"uid2"=>"1"}, {"uid2"=>"2"}],
 "query2"=>
  [{"uid"=>1, "name"=>"Foo bar"},
   {"uid"=>2, "name"=>"Bar Foo"}]}
```